# Why this code prints 4 stars instead of 2?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following C# code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<Task> tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 2)
            .Select(_ => Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Task.Delay(10);
                Console.Write("*");
            }));

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        Console.Write($"{tasks.Count()} stars!");
    }
}
```

It is indeterministic, I had it print two kinds of outputs:

- `**2 stars!**`
- `****2 stars!`

I can understand that stars might be in different positions, however I cannot understand why there are 4 stars? It seems to me that it should print 2 stars.

Comment: Both WhenAll and Count() enumerate `tasks`

Comment: <Martheen's comment>. Thus, it runs the tasks again.

Comment: use .ToList() or .ToArray() to only enumerate once - eg. https://dotnetfiddle.net/f30xLl

Comment: @b166er Uh, each task prints one star. The problem is that 4 tasks are ultimately created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tasks` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, meaning that it's lazily executed. So whenever you iterate through it, it will create a new set of tasks. When you call `tasks.Count()`, you create a new set of tasks which may or may not finish before the message is printed.

The proper fix would be:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 2)
    .Select(_ => Task.Run(() =>
    {
       Task.Delay(10);
       Console.Write("*");
    }))
    .ToList(); // create a list
```